# Reading an Excel file into an R dataframe from a zipped folder

Tags: r, xls, unzip

I have an Excel file (.xls extension) that is inside a zipped folder that I would like to read as a dataframe into R.  I loaded the gdata library and set up my working directory to the folder that houses the zipped folder.

When I type in the following syntax:

```
data_frame1 <- read.xls( unz("./Data/Project1.zip","schools.xls"))
```

I get the following error messages:

> Error in path.expand(xls) : invalid 'path' argument
>
> Error in file.exists(tfn) : invalid 'file' argument

I'm guessing that I'm missing some arguments in the syntax, but I'm not entirely sure what else needs to be included.

Thanks for your help!  This R newbie really appreciates it!

Comment: Do it in steps. Unzip first, find file with the correct extension and pass that to read.xls.

Comment: Does the `unz` work as shown?  You may try removing the './' before schools.xls.

Comment: Thanks @cdeterman. I just noticed the './', too and removed it.

Comment: @BenNorris, did that solve the problem then?

Comment: @cdeterman, I still get the same errors even after removing the './'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, after a quick survey of all the xls functions I know, there is no xls reading function that can recognize the `unz` output (I would love to be proven wrong here).  If it were a 'csv' it would work fine.  As it stands, until such a function is written, you must do the loading in two steps extraction and then loading.

To give you a little more control, you can specify which file to unzip as well as the directory to place the files with `unzip`.

```
# default exdir is current directory
unzip(zipfile="./Data/Project1.zip", files = "schools.xls", exdir=".")

dataframe_1 <- read.xls("schools.xls")
```

Sadly, this also means that you must do cleanup afterwards if you don't want the 'xls' file hanging around.

Comment: I can work with this solution!  Thanks for your help!