# I am unable to import in R a downloaded xls file

Tags: r, excel, import, download, data-mining

I am trying to directly import the .xls file that comes from [this link](https://eco2mix.rte-france.com/download/eco2mix/eCO2mix_RTE_En-cours-Consolide.zip) (French electricity distributor).

I have built, based on [this question](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763377/reading-an-excel-file-into-an-r-dataframe-from-a-zipped-folder), the folloning code :

```
library(rio)
Chemin = "F:/DGTresor/00.Refontes/06.Electricite_HauteFrequence" #WhateverPath

## RTE mois en cours
temporaire <- tempfile()

download.file("https://eco2mix.rte-france.com/download/eco2mix/eCO2mix_RTE_En-cours-TR.zip",temporaire)
              
unzip(zipfile=temporaire, 
      files = "eCO2mix_RTE_En-cours-TR.xls", 
      exdir=Chemin)

RTE_EnCours <- import(paste0(Chemin,"/eCO2mix_RTE_En-cours-TR.xls"))
```

The file exists, but I am unable to read it. I get the following error :   `libxls error: Unable to open file`

Comment: When I googled your error [this highly relevant issue thread came up](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/598). Perhaps you can try the `path.expand` solution that worked for Myfanwy?

Comment: I browsed it quickly. Unfortunately it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why it is happening but when I try to open the `.xls` file manually, it gives an error like *"The file format and its extension does not match"* etc. To solve the issue, I converted the file extension to `.csv` with the codes below.

```
file.rename(paste0(Chemin,"/eCO2mix_RTE_En-cours-TR.xls"), paste0(Chemin,"/eCO2mix_RTE_En-cours-TR.csv"))
```

After that, importing the file works,

```
# to prevent the shifting, header=FALSE should be applied
RTE_EnCours<- read.csv(paste0(Chemin,"/eCO2mix_RTE_En-cours-TR.csv"),sep="\t",header=FALSE,row.names=NULL)

# canceling out the last column which is full NA
RTE_EnCours <- RTE_EnCours[,-ncol(RTE_EnCours)] 

# assigning the first row as the column names
colnames(RTE_EnCours) <-as.character(unlist(RTE_EnCours[1,]))

# removing the first row
RTE_EnCours <- RTE_EnCours[-1,]

head(RTE_EnCours)
```

gives,

```
  Périmètre             Nature       Date Heures Consommation Prévision J-1 Prévision J Fioul Charbon  Gaz Nucléaire Eolien Solaire Hydraulique
2    France Données temps réel 2020-10-01  00:00        46957         46500       47100   134     286 4524     35004   4327       0        4645
3    France Données temps réel 2020-10-01  00:15        46342         45350       45950   149     318 4727     35278   4336       0        4953
4    France Données temps réel 2020-10-01  00:30        44689         44200       44800   149     304 4380     34732   4428       0        4580
5    France Données temps réel 2020-10-01  00:45        43277         42950       43700   165     308 4244     34644   4528       0        4147
6    France Données temps réel 2020-10-01  01:00        42511         41700       42600   165     302 4012     34780   4488       0        4096
7    France Données temps réel 2020-10-01  01:15        42714         41650       42750   165     297 4114     35145   4630       0        3758
  Pompage Bioénergies Ech. physiques Taux de Co2 Ech. comm. Angleterre Ech. comm. Espagne Ech. comm. Italie Ech. comm. Suisse
2    -751        1087          -2299          58                   179               -914             -1732             -1283
3    -750        1055          -3724          59                                                                             
4    -920        1045          -4009          58                   179               -914             -1732             -1283
5   -1861        1048          -3946          59                                                                             
6   -1857        1039          -4514          56                   497              -1759             -2279             -2217
7   -2005        1037          -4427          57                                                                             
  Ech. comm. Allemagne-Belgique Fioul - TAC Fioul - Cogén. Fioul - Autres Gaz - TAC Gaz - Cogén. Gaz - CCG Gaz - Autres
2                           -79           0             21            113        -2          585      3941            0
3                                         0             21            128        -1          580      4148            0
4                          -159           0             21            128        -1          580      3801            0
5                                         0             21            144        -1          582      3663            0
6                          1252           0             21            144        -1          579      3434            0
7                                         0             21            144        -1          581      3534            0
  Hydraulique - Fil de l?eau + éclusée Hydraulique - Lacs Hydraulique - STEP turbinage Bioénergies - Déchets Bioénergies - Biomasse
2                                 3355               1288                            2                   183                    447
3                                 3336               1615                            2                   174                    435
4                                 3242               1338                            0                   174                    434
5                                 3155                992                            0                   174                    437
6                                 3060               1036                            0                   172                    434
7                                 2992                766                            0                   177                    436
  Bioénergies - Biogaz
2                  301
3                  294
4                  294
5                  294
6                  294
7                  294
>
```

Comment: Good thinking. One slight issue with the result : the column names seem to be shifted by one

Comment: It is happening because in your data there exists 37th column which is full NULL. So R takes it as a new column. That is why it shifts. You should arrange the data after loading to overcome this issue. I updated the answer.

Comment: I thought it was coming from the first row, as I do not see why the import would see the missing column name as the first and not the last, which seems strange to me. Anyway, your solution works fine !

Comment: Then you may want to have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I thought I did so, sorry not to have done it sooner.